# Passing uiimage to new view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to create an array of images (from the web) and then pass this array to a new view. Here is the code I'm using:

```
WebViewController *webController = segue.destinationViewController;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[gift objectForKey:@"smallImageUrl"]];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
webController.image = image;
```

Also in my WebViewController.h i have:

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) UIImage *image;
```

But when I try to use "image" in WebViewController.m all i get is a (null) value. Where am I going wrong? Thanks!

UPDATE:
The problem appears to not be as I stated before. The image makes it to WebViewController. I am trying to save the image to an array which must be where my problem lies. This is the code I have for that in a saving method (in WebViewController.m):

```
NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[imageArray addObject:image];
[imageArray writeToFile:imageFileName atomically:YES];
```

also in my viewdidload i do:

```
paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
imageFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/imageArray",documentsDirectory];
```

Comment: When you assign webController, add a line below it "assert(webController);", which will cause a controller crash if that object is nil. Likewise add one below where you create the image, i.e.  assert(image);

Comment: you are assigned image to WebViewController, from where you are displaying the WebViewController ? Please post that portion also

Comment: @MidhunMP it looks like he's using storyboard based on `segue.destinationViewController` so the view will get displayed via that, it's something he doesn't have to worry about.

Comment: @MattS.: thanks matt for correcting me. :)

Comment: yes I am using storyboards... any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that the url is valid?

Comment: It might be that `image` is nil before you even set it to `webController.image`.

Comment: please see edits, i was mistaken in where the issue lay

Comment: What does `writeToFile:atomically:` return? Does it complete successfully?

Comment: hmm it returns false. how do i figure out why this is? thanks

Comment: ok so I'm thinking this is because I am trying to writeToFile an array of UIImages and writeToFile doesnt like UIImages. How can i make this work with an array of images?

Comment: Save the images as an array of `NSData`. You can convert them back to `UIImage` when you need them.